# Trigger to implement One ticket per active user per day

Tags: trigger, community

New to triggers. Excuse for silly mistakes. I have to implement a trigger for a custom object called Tickets with API - tickets__c. It contains Ticket No. , Assigned To(look up user),status.

Here is what i have tried but it is not allowing even one entry

```
   trigger ActiveFiveTrigger on Tickets__c (before insert, before update) {
   List<Tickets__c> TicketsList = Trigger.New;
   Map<id, Tickets__c> exMap= new map<Id, Tickets__c>();
   List<Tickets__C> TicketExisting = new List<Tickets__c>();
   List<Tickets__C> TicketActAssigned = new List<Tickets__c>();
   //List<AggregateResult> TicketActAssigned = new List<AggregateResult>();

   TicketExisting = [SELECT id,Name from tickets__c where status__c = 
   'Active' AND CreatedDate = TODAY]; 



  TicketActAssigned = [SELECT Id, Assigned_To__c FROM tickets__c WHERE 
  Status__c = 'Active' AND CreatedDate = TODAY ];
   exMap.putAll(TicketActAssigned);
  system.debug(exmap);

 for( Tickets__c TicketObj2 : TicketActAssigned){

    if(TicketObj2.Assigned_To__c == exmap.values().Assigned_To__c)
    { 
   TicketObj2.Assigned_To__c.addError('one active ticket per user in a day');
    }

 }






}
```

Comment: what is your business requirement?

Comment: We cannot know what you are doing is right or wrong, or possibly suggest a workaround unless we know what you are looking to achieve with the trigger. Please state your business requirements.

Comment: There are tickets created under tickets object. I want to give error if assigned user has more than one active ticket in one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding error to the records which are already present in the database won't throw error. You should add error to the records which are in transaction.

> Triggers can be used to prevent DML operations from occurring by
>   calling the addError() method on a record or field. When used on
>   Trigger.new records in insert and update triggers, and on Trigger.old
>   records in delete triggers, the custom error message is displayed in
>   the application interface and logged.

And in your code, you are comparing the values from the same list, you created the map using the list and iterating over the same list again and comparing it with the map i.e. your map `exMap` is created using `TicketActAssigned` list and you are iterating it again over the same list.

Also, you will have to handle the update scenario as well wherein the ticket can be reassigned to a user who might be already having active ticket assigned to him/her.

Below trigger should work for your scenario.

```
trigger ActiveFiveTrigger on Tickets__c(before insert, before update) {

    Map<Id, Tickets__c> mapExistingTickets = new Map<Id,Tickets__c>();
    for(Tickets__c ticket : [SELECT id, Name,Assigned_To__c from tickets__c where status__c = 'Active' AND CreatedDate = TODAY]){
        mapExistingTickets.put(ticket.Assigned_To__c,ticket);
    }

    for (Tickets__c lTicket: Trigger.New) {
        if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
            if(lTicket.Assigned_To__c!=null && lTicket.status__c == 'Active' && mapExistingTickets.containsKey(lTicket.Assigned_To__c)){
                lTicket.Assigned_To__c.addError('one active ticket per user in a day');
            }
        } else if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate){
            if(lTicket.Assigned_To__c!=null && lTicket.status__c == 'Active' && mapExistingTickets.containsKey(lTicket.Assigned_To__c)
                && Trigger.oldMap.get(lTicket.Id).Assigned_To__c != lTicket.Assigned_To__c){
                lTicket.Assigned_To__c.addError('one active ticket per user in a day');
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Note :** You should handle one more scenario where bulk tickets can be loaded at once and can be assigned to same user. In that case, you will have to check the records in transaction as well in addition to the records present in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement this requirement using workflow rule as well instead of going with trigger. Try these steps -

```
1) Create text field label 'Backend Assigned To' of unique type on Ticket object. 
(Don't add this field on page layout, only for backed purpose)
2) Create workflow rule on Ticket object. Criteria -> (Ticket: Status EQUALS Active) 
AND (Ticket: Assigned To NOT EQUAL TO null) AND (Ticket: Created Date EQUALS TODAY)
3) Create field update action-> Populate newly created 'Backend Assigned To' field 
with the value of 'Assigned To' field using formula.
```

Only limitation with workflow is that the error message that will be displayed is of standard type and can not be changed.